# Triggering JButtons via ENTER key?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm developing the GUI design for my database.

After designing most of the frame and debugging them I released I needed to add the option to 'trigger' buttons using **ENTER** key, instead of only clicking on it.

How should I go about it? I'm currently using **MouseListener** for my buttons and want to add a Listener that performs the same actions when ENTER key is pressed. Thank you

Comment: I believe you can just add a listener to your Form itself (or whatever interface you are using), then capture every keystroke pressed and if it equals "Enter" then you will just have it fire off the button's name. If you are unsure on how to do that, then I can look at it later tonight, but I need to know what kind of interface you are using and what your button name is please. :)

Comment: Thanks Austin, mind if I kindly ask for a sample code on how to properly do it. It's basically the Log In button I use when receiving user and password from my login frame. So enter user and password then press enter :)

Comment: @austiin how would you recommend differentiating the source of the event so you knew it was meant for the button? Assuming of course the event wasn't consumed and wasn't each by current focused components issues

Comment: Add the following line to your JFrame creation: frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);  You can only set one button to be your default (Enter) button.

Comment: ^ What Gilbert said. A JFrame can only have one listener on it, it will just ignore all other keystrokes based off how you set the "if" statement. I suppose you could have some kind of validation based on a checkbox being marked or something, but otherwise you can't differentiate anything. Having two listeners on the same Frame would be like having two remote unlock keys for the same car, it wouldn't do anything extra.

Comment: @Booch on a side note, are you using Netbeans or some other IDE? Netbeans is free and very strong UI-based Java IDE. Netbeans also allows for VERY EASY event_handlers to be tacked on to pretty much any type of Swing item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Enter key to invoke the Action of a button is a LAF issue. This is supported in Windows, but in the default Metal LAF you use the space bar.

Check out [Enter Key and Button](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/enter-key-and-button/) for a couple of solutions:

1. You can use the UIManager to make the button the default button as you tab from button to button: `UIManager.put("Button.defaultButtonFollowsFocus", Boolean.TRUE);`
2. You can use Key Bindings to map the Enter Key pressed/released events.

Answer (score 2):

You should never need to use a `MouseListener` with any kind of button. Instead you should be using an `ActionListener`. This will alert you when the button is clicked or activated by the keyboard based on the requirements of the look and feel

Take a look at [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details