# How to connect JButton to keyboard "ENTER" key?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I dont have any idea how to connect JButton "b" to keyboard key "ENTER"?

> Java

```
b=new JButton(icon);
b.setBounds(285, 50, 40, 30);

b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String ip;
        String url=tf.getText();

        try {
            ip=java.net.InetAddress.getByName(url).getHostAddress();
            l2.setText("IP address:"+ip);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }  

    }
});
add(b);
```

Comment: add a keylistener https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_key_listener.htm

Comment: Perhaps you want to set a `JButton` as the default button? This is explained in the section entitled [How to Use JButton Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#jbutton) on the Web page _How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons_ which is part of Oracle's _Swing_ tutorial.

Comment: See: [Triggering Buttons via Enter Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769423/triggering-jbuttons-via-enter-key/23771988#23771988) for a couple of different approaches depending on your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply re-bind the key actions. By default ButtonUI uses the "SPACE" key to invoke the action. Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * <code>ButtonKeyTest</code>.
 */
public class ButtonKeyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ButtonKeyTest()::startUp);
    }

    private void startUp() {
        JButton b = new JButton("Use Enter Luke!");
        b.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(b, "Yeah!"));
        // rebind "space" action to "enter" for key pressed event
        Object actId = b.getInputMap().get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0));
        b.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), actId);
        // rebind "space" action to "enter" for key released event
        actId = b.getInputMap().get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true));
        b.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, true), actId);
        // end rebind

        // alternative
        // b.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "pressed");
        // b.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, true), "released");

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(b);
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Button");
        frm.add(p);
        frm.setSize(200, 100);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

More information about key bindings you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a KeyListener instead of ActionListener and check the `KeyEvent` e with `int keyCode = e.getKeyCode()`. Here is a proper example:

```
private JButton button;

public Foo() {
    button = new JButton("click");
    // frame settings - width/height etc.
    this.add(button);

    button.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // your logic here
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                System.out.println("ENTER PRESSED");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // your logic here
        }
    });

}
```

**PS** : it's not a really good approach adding a key listener on a button ( the name says it, the key listener should be added on an input type - textarea, textfield etc. ).

Comment: (1-) Swing was designed to be used with "Key Bindings" (not KeyListeners). Also, the code here doesn't invoke the default ActionListener added to the button. That is the OP should be able to click on the button or use the Enter key to invoke the same  action.

Comment: He didn't said that he want to be able to use the click and the enter button to do the same action.